# Difference between connecting using Name or IP in Active Directory environment

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory

Anyone know if are there any real authentication differences between connecting using Name or IP in Active Directory environment.
The environment is standard and well configured.

Comment: You can't connect to a DFS share by IP, so that's a difference right there...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IP address = NTLM only.
Kerberos uses names.

**Kerberos is not used when you connect to SMB shares by using IP address**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322979

"When a client uses Kerberos to authenticate itself to a server, the client requests a session ticket for the Service Principal Name (SPN). IP addresses are not names, so Kerberos is not used. After this occurs, the server goes through the list of the other supported security providers."

Answer (score 2):

Your question is rather broad, but it's generally considered poor practice to use IP addresses for anything like file shares or print shares when you have a functioning DNS environment.